# xmlhttprequest variables undefined ONLY in IE8

Tags: javascript

I have the following script working in all major browsers except for Internet Explorer.  All of my variables are coming back undefined.

```
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {
 xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
else
 {
 xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
} 
var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("nhl_standings_xml.xml");
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("nhlall");
```

Some other info..

xhttp.readystate = 4
xhttp.status=200

I am using .textContent to get the variables, however, I have read that sometimes IE has problems with that. Can someone maybe give me some ideas about alternatives to .textContent?

here is what the rest of code looks like:

```
     document.getElementById('PensWins').innerHTML = var1;
    document.getElementById('PensLoses').innerHTML = var3;
    document.getElementById('PensOTWins').innerHTML = var8;

             var var1 = x[i+3].textContent;
        var var3 = x[i+4].textContent;
        var var8 = x[i+5].textContent;
```

'i' is coming from a loop

im asking is there any part of the above IE8 doesn't like?  (obviously there is)

Comment: WHICH PART FAILS? The xhr part? OR the `getElementsByTagName("nhlall")` part? Or the `.textContent` part which you failed to show us?

Comment: well i'm not really sure.. giving that the readystate and status of the xhr comes back fine, i don't think it's that.. the get elementsbytagname part doesn't fail because it works in all other browsers. i will post the code of .textcontent so you can tell me what u think.  i updated my post above.

Comment: IE8 does have some almost usable debugger - it might be worth installing that and stepping through.